How can I update the symbols list exported from common area for the vendor and other areas of a gki kernel?
I'm developing a module in the common area of the kernel, but from the vendor area (module) I need to access some registering functions in the common area. I saw that the functions from common area can be exported to vendor and other areas through the "android/abi_gki_aarch64" and "android/abi_gki_aarch64.xml". I need most probably to update those lists. Very little documentation so far on how can I do this. The xml file contains some crc checks which I don't know where to get them. Struggling for 1 day so far. Maybe someone else encountered this problem before. Thanks.
I've updated the abi_gki_aarch64 by hand but it does not seem to cut it. Probably it has something to do with the "build_abi.sh" script.

you asking about android specifics. please set appropriate tags.

I found out myself after all, you need to build for abi indeed (build_abi.sh) with the common kernel config. After that look into dist folder for the exported symbols (xml) file, get your symbol and put it in the android/abi_gki_aarch64.xml file. Now the symbol will be exported from common area to other areas (vendor or something else).
